# Create a image File from a Image widget

Tags: flutter, image, file, dart, widget

I'm developing an application where the user of my App must upload images to Firebase Storage, and for that, they need to be in File format.

Part of the images come from the web, that is, they were obtained through the `Image.network()` method. Another part comes from the cell phone gallery, and was obtained by the `ImagePicker` package.

Even coming from different sources, all images are being grouped in a `List<Image>`. Now, I need to upload this list of images to Storage, but for that I need to convert them to File and I don't know how to do that, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should save image from network url to file, it is better like this

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';



 Future<File> _fileFromImageUrl() async {
        final response = await http.get('https://example.com/abc.jpg');
    
        final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    
        final file = File(join(documentDirectory.path, 'imagetest.png'));
    
        file.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
    
        return file;
      }
```

After that add this to you image list with the image taken from image picker.
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();      
final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source:ImageSource.gallery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the image and save the file in the followwing way.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> _fileFromImageUrl() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://example.com/xyz.jpg');

    final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final file = File(join(documentDirectory.path, 'imagetest.png'));

    file.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);

    return file;
  }
```